# Can't "paint" on a image file in order to render a function

Tags: java

I'm working right now on a function render, that basically gives values to a function and "paints" the corresponding pixel in my image. For some reason, the image is generated, but it's absolutely blank. Any idea?

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(500, 250,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        for (int x = -100; x <= 100; x++) {

            try {
                int y = f(x);

                bi.setRGB(xconverter(x), yconverter(y), 0);
                System.out.println("f(" + x + ") = " + y);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

        }

        try {
            File f = new File("/home/pitazzo/Escritorio/Final.png");
            ImageIO.write(bi, "png", f);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static int xconverter(int x) {
        return x + 250;
    }

    public static int yconverter(int y) {
        return y + 125;
    }

    public static int f(int x) {

        return ((x * x) + (7 * x) - 2) / (x + 18);
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Hey, did you saw my answer?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the color:

```java
bi.setRGB(xconverter(x), yconverter(y), 0);
```

The 0 means 0 alpha, 0 red, 0 green and 0 blue. And 0 alpha means transparent - oops! You need to use an opaque color (0xFF alpha).

Use this:

```java
bi.setRGB(xconverter(x), yconverter(y), 0xFF_00_00_00); // Black
```